# How do I include a JS file from a node_module in my view in Roots?

Tags: javascript, node.js, roots-toolkit

I'm using roots (http://roots.cx) and I want to include a library from a node_module in my page. I've `npm install foo` and the library is on disk.

I've tried adding `foo` to the `extensions` in app.coffee and restarted the watcher but the path it's rendering is to the node_modules folder which does not resolve from the browser.

```
extensions: [
    js_pipeline(files: 'node_modules/foo/lib/foo.js', 'assets/js/*.coffee'),
    css_pipeline(files: 'assets/css/*.styl')
  ]
```

and in the page source I get

```
<script src='node_modules/foo/lib/foo.js'></script>
```

What is the correct way to include a library from a node module?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead with the `./` since it's only a file and not a module, like this:

```
extensions: [
    js_pipeline(files: './node_modules/foo/lib/foo.js', 'assets/js/*.coffee'),
    css_pipeline(files: 'assets/css/*.styl')
  ]
```

Otherwise try to extract or copy the file from the `node_modules` and put it in a separate folder

Comment: No change :( I've got disable cache enabled too.